# CSS: why does this css rule not work in google Chrome

Tags: css

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, green, blue);
```

I just want my page looks same in Chrome, while some element is styled by a IE filter:

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled='true',startColorstr=#88888888,endColorstr=#88CCCCCC);

Comment: What do you want the gradient to look like?

Comment: There's a webkit version of linear-gradient?

Comment: Here, OP: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient/

Comment: This isn't meant to answer the question, but I find it useful to create my gradients using this useful utility: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/. It shows you the CSS code for all browsers (including IE) and has support for color stops in the gradient.

Comment: I saw that from webkit sit, but not work in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you need [-webkit-gradient](http://webkit.org/blog/175/introducing-css-gradients/). To make as your ie filter you need to use the following:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#888), color-stop(100%,#88C));
```

Comment: for opacity you need -webkit-opacity: 1.0 (values 1.0-0.0)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest nightly developer build?

http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2011/01/18/webkit-updates-css3-gradient-support-matches-mozilla-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

`-webkit-linear-gradient` works on Chrome 10+